# How to get parent splitviewcontroller from view(xib)

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I'm currently able to achieve this with Storyboards using:

```
 var parentSplit : NSSplitViewController? {
    guard let splitVC = parent as? NSSplitViewController else { return nil }
    return splitVC
}
```

but it returns `nil` if I try it in a xib file. My view is a subview in a SplitView.

Comment: At what stage of view cycle are you trying to use it ?

Comment: I found I had to create the SplitView programmatically. Its working now but I'm having issues setting the split bar